# React Native saves old Text Input data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I have a text input that saves to a setState on each change. However if I hit the cancel button which takes me back a page, and then I go back to the first page, my changes are still on the first page.

I feel that this might be the phone that is saving cache or something on my page but how can I make this value reset?

I am also using react navigation for my page navigation

```
<TextInput
    ref={ref => this.companyNameInput = ref}
    onChangeText={text => { setCompanyNameInput(text); setSaveFlag(true);}}
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 150,
        color: 'rgba(0, 159, 150, 1)'

    }}
>
    <Text12
        style={{
            color: 'rgba(0, 159, 150, 1)',
            padding: 0,
            marginBottom: 0
        }}
    >
        {companyNameInput}
    </Text12>

</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your text input when you press cancel button

```
let companyNameInput = null; //if this is functional component else class then use this
const onCancel = () => {
   companyNameInput.clear()
}
```

**Or** you can set event listener on blur of current screen like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
        onCancel();
   })
}. [props.navigation])
```

you can also clear your state variable by this

```
setCompanyNameInput('');
```

**NOTE:** if you are using class component then use componentWillUnmount instead of useEffect, **"this"** only works on class based component